# unable to mock clientmethod returning Single<? extends HttpResponse> using Mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito, rx-java2, micronaut

I'm building a microservice using Micronaut. This particular service depends on a automatically generated client from another service, that I'd like to mock in my component tests.

However I'm unable to mock one of the methods of the apiClient. it's signaute looks like this:

```
    Single<? extends HttpResponse> patchProfile(String userId, UserprofileApiEntity userProfile);
```

where `HttpResponse` is from the package  `io.micronaut.http` and `Single` comes from the package `io.reactivex`

In my test, I'm trying to mock this endpoint as such:

```
        when(userProfileClientMock.patchProfile(userIdCaptor.capture(), profileCaptor.capture())).thenReturn(Single.just(HttpResponse.ok()));
```

however I'm getting the error

```
error: no suitable method found for thenReturn(Single<CAP#1>)
        when(userProfileClientMock.patchProfile(userIdCaptor.capture(), profileCaptor.capture())).thenReturn(response);
                                                                                                 ^
    method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(Single<CAP#2>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Single<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Single<CAP#2>)
    method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(Single<CAP#2>,Single<CAP#2>...) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Single<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Single<CAP#2>)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends HttpResponse from capture of ? extends HttpResponse
    CAP#2 extends HttpResponse from capture of ? extends HttpResponse
Note: /home/anders/Documents/minecraft/minecraft.api.public.displaynames/minecraft.api.public.displaynames.server/src/test/java/net/minecraft/api/pub/displaynames/DisplaynamesApiTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

from what I gather it's got something to do with the `<? extends . . .>` part of the signature, I've successfully mocked different methods from similar apiclients returning stuff like `Single<Foo>` or `Maybe<Bar>`
unfortunately in this case it does not make sense to change the signature of the client.

I've tried specifying the response single as a variable, explicitly typing it as `Single<? extends HttpResponse>` and `Single<MutableHttpResponse>` thinking maybe mockito was confused by type-erasure somehow, but to no avail.

any ideas what might be the cause of this, and how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I was eventually able to solve this, using a different mockito grammar, namely

```
doReturn(foo).when(bazMock).barMethod();
```

this style of mocking does not provide type-safety, which is a bit of a trade-off, but here seems to be a necessary evil. I would guess this applies to any case where you want to mock something returning a generic class typed as `foo<? extends bar>`

Comment: Is this better or worse than making the Single generic? I ran into this same problem with CryptoResult<byte[], ?> and could also solve by classing it CryptoResult. At least then there's Type protection of the top-level class. I don't know if it's a step forward or backward here.

Comment: not sure what you mean? Single is already a generic class. Do you mean removing the type the actual method in order to provide type safety in the test? I guess there are scenarios where that might make sense, but in the case of Single that would just remove typsafety from your actual program and add basically nothing to your test, as Single<> basically just means that the result will be returned asynchronously.